# Converting An nsarray to nsmutablearray of dictionaries in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I had an IPhone application in which i had an array of elements,But i need each element inside a dictionary,i.e. (nsmuatblearray of dictionaries),I did like this But some times its giving some unwanted results 
`

```
id objectInstance;
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (objectInstance in self.SelectedContacts)
        [mutableDictionary setObject:objectInstance forKey:@"tag"];
         [finalarray addObject:mutableDictionary];
```

`
I am doing like this Can anybody points me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing it is overwriting the element for the key "tag" every time. I am not entirely sure what are you trying to accomplish, but I suspect you should write something like:

```
for (id objectInstance in self.SelectedContacts) {
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [mutableDictionary setObject:objectInstance forKey:@"tag"];
    [finalarray addObject:mutableDictionary];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the loop you are putting different object with same tag name "tag". So here only the last objectInstance is getting saved, rest all are replaced by next one.

If you want each one of them to be saved, then update your "tag" with new tag-names.

Another thing, either you missed to show `{` in code above or if you *really* don't have those braces `{` and `}` for `for` then only next one line is taken up with the loop and `[finalarray addObject:mutableDictionary];` is executed once!!!

Comment: Can u help me how to make it the reverse i.e. from an array of dictionaries to just an array

Comment: you can use valueForKey: that will return array. And you may also enjoy posting a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here no need to create `NSMutableDictionary` because you just use it to save it in array no further modification is there.

Also it will consume more memory than `NSDictionary`. In future if you want to update object in dictionary that you can convert `NSDictionary` to `NSMutableDictionary` using

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:object];
```

and vice versa to `NSDictionary`.

Right now a simple way to add dictionary in array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *finalArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *object in self.SelectedContacts) {
    [finalArray addObject:@{ @"tag" : object }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure from your question if you want an array of dictionaries each with the same key, or an array with 1 dictionary in it.

Many dictionaries version

```
for (long i = 0; i < [self.SelectedContacts count];i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [mutableDictionary setObject:[self.SelectedContacts objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"tag"];
    [finalarray addObject:mutableDictionary];
}
```

1 dictionary version

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (long i = 0; i < [self.SelectedContacts count];i++)
{
    NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tag_%li",i];
    [mutableDictionary setObject:[self.SelectedContacts objectAtIndex:i] forKey:keyString];
}

[finalarray addObject:mutableDictionary];
```

in this 1 dictionary version the tags will be tag_ followed by the old index value in the array.

tag_0
tag_1
etc.